# How to clean cash and cookies from React Native Axios basic authentication values?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I am using below code to basic authenticate via rest api using axios in react native app. Basic Authentication works, but after initial successful authentication , rest Api always takes last success authenticated(username and password ) for post basic authentication and it never takes current auth values. Currently i am testing on iphone simulataor. i have to restart entire simulator to allow post to take updated username and password.
How can i delete last saved auth values ?

```
function post1() {
    axios
      .post(
        'https://....',
        {
          withCredentials: false,

          headers: {
            
            Accept: 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
          },
        },{
         
          auth: {
            username: 'user1',
            password: 'password1'
          },
          data: {
            action: 'actionsecond ',
          },
        }
      )
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.status);
        
        }
        console.log('data', response.data);

      
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error.data);
        console.log("password", password);

      });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

After researching , i came to know that axios never store cache or cookies and every cache and cookies are  created by react native project. And best way to clear all cookies is using below code with the help of clearCookies

```
    const RCTNetworking = require('react-native/Libraries/Network/RCTNetworking'); 
    RCTNetworking.clearCookies((result) => {
    console.log(result) //true if successfully cleared
```